# Smell from laundry drain, possibly no vent?

Tags: drain, smell, venting, p-trap

Just purchased a home that was renovated.  Appears to have not been by a professional, nothing major but small things.  Not sure what to do on this one.  There is a smell coming from the in wall drain.  Is this because it was not vented properly or needs a p trap?  [image]

Comment: All drains need U pipe.

Comment: There should be a *standpipe* there that leads down into a trap inside the wall -- you may need to use an inspection camera or just remove a bit of drywall to see it though